# Priority of Vue directives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used a form component of a Third Party Component Library, which hasn't disabled props, and I bind a click event to every form item via @click to popup a dialog when the form item was clicked. But here is my problem, in some case the form item should not be clickable, so I create a custom prevent-click directive which like this:

```
const clickHandler = e => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  e.stopPropagation()
  return false
}

const directive = {
  bind(el, { value }) {
    if (value) {
      el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, true)
    }
  },
  update(el, { value }) {
    if (!value) {
      el.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, true)
    } else {
     el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, true)
    }
  }
}
```

used like this:

```
<form-item v-prevent-click="true" @click="showDialog"></form-item>
```

The prevent-click directive do nothing but add a captured event listener to the form-item, which stop the propagation, everything goes well so far, but the problem is that the form-item has a pseudo child element which is added by css after selector. So when I clicked the pseudo child element, due to the pseudo child element itself doesn't dispatch the click event instead of the form-item, so the form-item element will still dispatch the event, besides the vue builtin directive @click event handler was bound first, which result in the useCapture param of addEventListener method won't effect.

In the 1.x version, there is priority option of custom directive, but the 2.X remove it. So are there anyway to make my custom directive bind before than the builtin @click?

Comment: Can you make use of Event Modifiers? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers and attach the prevent call directly to the @click?

Comment: emmmm, I have already checked the Event Modifiers, and I don't think they work for my situation....

Comment: You could also try to add `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Vue's built-in event modifiers (reference [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)). Try this:

```
<form-item @click.stop.prevent="showDialog"></form-item>
```

I don't know what your third-party components framework is, but if you really need to handle the `preventDefault` by yourselft, I suggest you to do the following:

**Template**

```
<form-item @click="showDialog"></form-item>
```

**Script**

```
methods: {
    showDialog(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Your code to display dialog...
    }
}
```

If you also need to pass arguments to `showDialog`, remember that you can - just pass the event as first argument:

```
<form-item @click="showDialog($event, urData)"></form-item>
```

Comment: emmm, I really don't want to change the showDialog code, that's why I want to use custom directive. But I'll try thatif there is absolutely no way to achieve that by custom directive

Comment: I really have no idea why you need to do that. What about [sharing more informations in your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Like the 3rd party component library you are using, which are the cases the component should not be clickable, why in your opinion the builtin event modifiers won't work and why you absolutely need a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing a flag to `showDialog`. If you cannot modify `showDialog` function wrap it in another function:

```
// Your compoennt template
<form-item @click="wrappedShowDialog(true)"></form-item>

// Vue.js component
wrappedShowDialog(isAllowed) {
    if (isAllowed) {
        this.showDialog();
    }
}
```